# How to open the these Android app store directly from my Android application?

Tags: android, opera

Most Android apps have a menu item called **Rate App**, which when clicked opens up the corresponding app page in app store. Considering my app has a package name = com.good.app

I will use

market://details?id=com.good.app

to open my app in Google Play Store app or

**https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.good.app**

to open my app page in device browser.

My question is what are the corresponding URIs for opening my app's page is app stores like:

- Appland
- Apptoide
- Samsung Android App Store
- Opera Mobile Store (considering it only has a web app store)
- Etc

Comment: I do not know if the document is up-to-date, but you find some information about Samsung App Store here : http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Samsung-Apps-Deeplink-Guide

Comment: @rolandl Thanks for the information. The Web links are not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AndroidRate](https://github.com/Vorlonsoft/AndroidRate) or it's source code. AndroidRate is a library to help you promote your android app by prompting users to rate the app after using it for a few days.

Answer (score -1):

Open your browser and search your app.
copy link and replace in:

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("link"));
startActivity(intent);

You cannot open your app in any other app store, but Google Play, directly from your application.

Comment: But then I will have to update my app with the links soon after releasing the first version of my app.